# How do I make a build show up in my TeamCity public NuGet feed?

Tags: teamcity, nuget, nuget-server

We use TeamCity 7.1.1 to publish NuGet packages on both the authenticated and public feed URLs. I've just created a new package and can't get it to show up on the public feed, though it does appear on the private feed once I log in.

It smacks of a permissions problem, but I've assigned 'All Users' the 'Project Viewer' role on that build. I have another build that is showing up correctly, and the configuration seems the same. What could be stopping my new build from appearing on the public feed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved it! I've been scratching my head for hours and of course I find the answer 30 seconds after posting to StackOverflow!

It seems that the Guest account is not a member of All Users, so assigning the Project Viewer role to All Users is not sufficient.

One has to explicitly assign the Project Viewers role to the Guest User. This is confusingly done in a completely separate screen, under ***Guest user settings***, linked from the top right hand side of the main user administration screen. Walla! Job done.

Comment: I believe you can close this question as it is not relevant and much obvious

Comment: Things are always obvious once you have the answer - it took me several hours to find it and I believe that makes it non-obvious. I also think its relevant, but then I'm completely biased because its my question. But if it really offends your sensibilities, go ahead and flag it up for moderator attention and we'll let them decide.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Our public NuGet feed stopped showing up in projects for some reason, so annoying, and now it works fine again, thanks!

Comment: Another person here that is grateful for you posting this @TimLong, thank you very much.